# Issue with selecting date from calendar in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to select current date from the calendar on this website "www.makemytrip.com".
Using these 2 lines of code:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='departure']")).click();`

To open the calendar and to select date:

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".DayPicker-Day.DayPicker-Day--selected.DayPicker-Day--today")).click();`

The first one is working fine as it opens up the calendar but cssSelector is not responding. I've tried various variations but still it remains unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath strategy:

`//div[@class='DayPicker-Day DayPicker-Day--today']`

Now, i write in python, so you may translate my code to Java, since most of it remains same.
`time.sleep` (`Thread.sleep` in Java) here is optional Ideally you should use `WebdriverWait` instead of Thread.sleep. But just to show you, I used it.

```
driver.get('https://www.makemytrip.com/')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@for='departure']").click()
time.sleep(1)
dx = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='DayPicker-Day DayPicker-Day--today']")
print(dx.text)
dx.click()
```

Here is the output:
17 is the date and the other value is currency.

```
17
₹ 9,418

Process finished with exit code 0
```